# assemble not working when add dataBinding

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

some help will be appreciate a lot. I'm implementing Jenkins for CI, my project works fine, and in Jenkins I wanted to implement gradle script in Jenkins, easy one "assembleDebug" just for testing, that's when things started been crazy.

It starts with this problem when calling ./gradlew app:assembleDebug

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

After a lot of research I found that this library was deprecated in Java 9, so I just add this line to my gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Build my project locally and start working again. But in Jenkins is not working its return the message that is not a valid JAVA_HOME. I suppose I should not use local variables even if the server is in my local machine.

I create a new project and start adding libraries to catch the problem, and I found that the problem occurs when I add:

```
android {
   ...
   dataBinding {
     enabled = true
   }
   ...
```

If I remove those lines gradle run with no problem. even from a brand new project.
This is what I get from my ./gradle --version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          12.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 12.0.1+12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

I really appreciate if someone give some light about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you update your Gradle wrapper.  If you are using Android Studio it should offer to do this (involves changing files in the `./gradle` folder and `build.gradle`).

I had a very similar error in my case I was running this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1 which provided a code here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-navigation with a latest commit 3e94562 on 9 Nov 2019

With the checked out code, I was running similar to you:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          11.0.7 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.7+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.6 x86_64
```

and had the error you describe, simply upgrading Gradle the error went away and the Gradle version changed to:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-06-02 20:46:21 UTC
Revision:     a27f41e4ae5e8a41ab9b19f8dd6d86d7b384dad4

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.7 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.7+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.6 x86_64
```